# How To Get Super Parent in Custom Property Update Function in Python

Tags: python, objects, collections

I have `Collection_A` attached to `Object` and `Collection_B` attached to `Collection_A`,

```py
Object > Collection_A > Collection_B
```

Now, In `Collection_B` update value function, we can access instance of `Collection_A` with `self`.
But, How can I access `Object` variable?

Comment: Yes @Gorgious it does, `repr()` function is awesome. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Glad to help. If you want a pointer to the object use `self.id_data`

Comment: `self.id_data` can also solve this for objects, nice to know, thanks

Comment: @Gorgious, I tried `id_data` it is giving `Scene` for Scene Properties and `Armature` for Armature Properties, It's exactly doing, what is want...